# transition padding bug in Safari?

Tags: css, css-transitions, safari

I created a little title tab that on hover has its padding-right transition over 1sec. I've tested it in Chrome, Opera, IE10 and FF and it works as expected. Oddly enough in Safari it doesn't pick up the transition at all. In fact, it also shifts the element 1px to the right on hover. I haven't run into any specific case like this so wasn't sure if it is known bug or an oversight on my part. Here is the code:

HTML

`<h2 class="screen-button about-button">About</h2>`

CSS

```
.screen-button {
    border-radius: 0 0 14px 14px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .3em .5em .4em;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: padding-right 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: padding-right 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: padding-right 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: padding-right 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: padding-right 1s ease-in-out;
}

.screen-button:hover {
    padding-right: 91%;
}

.about-button {
    background: rgb(69,237,248);
    background: rgba(69,237,248, .8);
}
```

Here is the Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/julsfelic/m429p/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you want to animate from `em` to `%` and in Safari is not working. Try to set the padding for both normal and hover state using the same unit. At least padding-right (ex: `padding: .3em 3% .4em`).

Comment: ***Blast*** that's the solution. Thanks Christian. That makes it really hard though because I'm trying to go from a 20px padding to a 20% padding, which apparently this can't do. Have to use a wrap with 20px to 0px, and 0% to 20% to get around this.